# Obj-c crash when UINavigationController pushing UIViewController which creates SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So myself and a group of students are working on a game for IOS. We started by having two separate projects, one that would be making the menus, shop, credits, tutorial, etc.

And the other project would work on the game itself, then merge the two together via github and attach the 'play button' on our main menu, which is a navigation controller with a hidden control bar with a view controller inside it.

The problem currently is that the game runs fine on its own, but trying to get it integrated into the main menu project causes it to crash.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

this is the code inside our game's view controller.

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenu = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenu];

[navCont setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

[self.window setRootViewController:navCont];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
```

Here is our `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function

and finally:

```
-(void) startNewGame
{
    NSLog(@"Game Started!");

    //ViewController *v = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:v animated:NO];
    CGFloat winWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat winHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    //CGSize s = CGSizeMake(winWidth, winHeight);


    SKView *v  = (SKView *)self.view;

    v.showsFPS = YES;
    v.showsNodeCount = YES;

    SKScene *myScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:v.bounds.size];
    myScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [v presentScene:myScene];
}
```

Here is our `StartGame()` function, which is called when a button is pressed on the main menu view controller.

What needs to be done to get this to work? I fear we are going to have to rewrite the menus to get them to be compatible with the game....

Comment: What is the error you get, where does it crash? You need to provide more information.

Comment: i said it crashes on the call to create the SKScene in the last bit of code i attached.

Comment: You should get an exception message in the console that says *why* it crashes. What you have said here is equivalent to telling your mechanic that there is "something wrong with your car" - you need to provide specific details before we can help you.

Comment: reason: '-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb79b425800'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're trying to call the method setShowsFPS on a UIView, and of course, UIView doesn't have such a method. Apparently your controller's self.view is a UIView not a SKView. You probably didn't change the class of the controller's view to SKView in the storyboard.

Comment: Awesome! now its less broken! :D. now it successfully pushes the view controller and creates the SKScene, but now im stuck with a black background. But ill make a different thread for that once ive given it a try myself.